# ¿Como obtener datos de un usuario con firebase y react JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo obtener solo un name de la base de datos ya que que me esta arrojando mas de un name **ejemplo de como se ve**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora bien yo solo quiero obterner el nombre del id de ingreso y no los dos

**adjunto el codigo que estoy utilizando**

```js
class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    db.onceGetUsers().then(snapshot =>
      this.setState(() => ({
         users: snapshot.val() 
        }))
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>Todos los usuarios que inician sesión tienen acceso a la Página de inicio.</p>

        { !!users && <UserList users={users} /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const UserList = ({ users }) =>
  <div className="App">
    
     {Object.keys(users).map(key =>
      <div key={key}>{users[key].username}</div>
      
     )}


  </div>

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(HomePage);
```

igual adjunto una imagen de la referencia de la db

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

& de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Francisco por favor detalla como esta estructurada tu base de datos y un ejemplo de lo que te gustaria lograr para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

asumo que 'users' es el nodo donde almacenas una lista de usuarios en ese caso tendrías una lista parecida a esta

```
users
 - XXXXXXX1
    - nombre = 'TESTNOMBRE1'
    - password = '********1'
 - XXXXXXX2
    - nombre = 'TESTNOMBRE2'
    - password = '********2'
```

Cuando obtienes el nodo 'users' `con db.ref('users').once('value')`, lo que estas haciendo es obteniendo toda la lista de usuarios.

Para obtenr un usuario en especifico lo que debes hacer es referenciar al hijo (child) de users identificándolo por su ID `XXXXXXX1`

Si quiero obtener al segundo usuario de mi lista debo consultarlo de esta manera

```
db.ref('users').child('XXXXXXX2').once('value')
```

Tambien debes tomar en cuenta que si obtienes toda la lista de usuarios con `db.ref('users').once('value')` estas descargando toda la lista de usuarios, si hay 100 mil usuarios dentro de users, todos esos usuarios se descargaran a tu aplicación y eso no es lo que quieres hacer, o no deberías.

Comment: No ah funcionado como lo planteas, ¿hay alguna otra manera?

Comment: Sin conocer la estructura de tu BD solo puedo inferirla de la manera que lo hice, si puedes detallar mas su estructura te podría ayudar mejor